# How to toggle between two background images for a div having an event listener

Tags: javascript, html

It's a to do list and here's the JS I'm stuck into -

```js
function taskCheck() {
    let taskCheckboxImg = this.style.backgroundImage;
    if(taskCheckboxImg=="url('img/uncheck.png')") {
        taskCheckboxImg="url('img/check.png')";
    } else {
        taskCheckboxImg="url('img/uncheck.png')";
    }
}
```

I want to toggle between check and uncheck by changing the background image when clicked but the if statement doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it doesn't change the background image property in the 4th line.

I could have done this with a regular checkbox but it doesn't seem to have editable properties in CSS. Help!

Comment: I would would suggest that you move this logic to a css-class and toggle that instead. Let the css-class add the background. And then toggle the css-class for your html-element.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value to a `variable`, **i*nstead you need to change the value of the CSS property*** after each condition like

```
this.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/check.png')";
```

Also, you are using `this`, which refers to the current object, so make sure you have the `this` context available from wherever you call `taskCheck()` function

---

You function after the change should look like below

```
function taskCheck() {
    let taskCheckboxImg = this.style.backgroundImage;
    if(taskCheckboxImg=="url('img/uncheck.png')") {
        this.style.backgroundImage="url('img/check.png')";
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundImage="url('img/uncheck.png')";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('div')
myDiv.addEventListener('click', taskCheck)

function taskCheck(e) {
    let taskCheckboxImg = e.target.style.backgroundImage;

    if(taskCheckboxImg=='url("https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200")') {

            // you have to change css property like this
        e.target.style.backgroundImage='url("https://picsum.photos/id/300/200/200")';
    } else {
    console.log(taskCheckboxImg)
    
        e.target.style.backgroundImage='url("https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200")';
    }
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/200')"></div>
```